# "Your age" in the phrase of "a boy your age" modifies "a boy"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, nouns, modifiers

> But I'm amazed at how a boy *"your age"* understood what my job was.

I'd think that's a modifier because in the how clause, the *subject* of *understood* seems to be "*a boy*", not "your age". Yet, I'm not sure undoubtedly whether "your age" modifies "a boy". Is it possible for me to paraphrase "*a boy your age*" into "*a boy **of** your age*"?

Comment: i would say it qualifies not modifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reasonable paraphrase. The phrase *your age* is, indeed, modifying *boy*

They are indicating that their amazement is partly based on your age. Indeed, the fact you are a boy might be irrelevant (depending on just what the job was), but instead be referring to you as a boy and saying that they are surprised that *someone* your age understood their job.

Comment: Thanks for your helping me. Might I inquire of you something which is out of curiosity? Can I paraphrase "a boy your age" into "a boy of your age" without affecting the meaning?

Comment: In that specific case, yes. "A boy your age" sounds more natural to me, but people wouldn't generally think odd of "a boy of your age". It won't apply to all such modifiers, though.

Answer (score 0):

See https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/312729/139225:

> This is a very particular construction consisting of two noun phrases, where the second part is a noun phrase serving as modifier within the larger noun phrase. The second part describes some property, like size, shape, or color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "your age" modifies the noun phrase "a boy". But I don't know of any grammar rules that allow optional elision of prepositions, so it makes more sense to think of the deeper structure as a *reduced relative clause*.

A reduced relative clause is one where the relative pronoun and verb are removed. This can happen when the relative pronoun is the subject and the verb is a "be"-verb. A simple example:

> *I made friends with someone **who is** in my class*.

Here, "who is" can be omitted without changing the meaning. It's also more natural.

So I suspect the deep structure of your sentence is:

> *But I'm amazed at how a boy **who is** your age understood what my job was*.

When we omit "who is", we're left with your original sentence, and "your age" continues to modify "a boy".